# Search for an image within a group of images

Tags: php, arrays, image, search

I have a bunch of pictures
I want to search for a specific image within the picture
I want to check if this image is available in the matrix

```
<?php 
$ima="image1.PNG";

$md5image1 = md5(file_get_contents($ima));

$images=array( "image1.PNG","image2.PNG","image3.PNG","image4.PNG"  ); 
srand(time()); 
shuffle($images); 
    for ($i=0;$i<5;++$i)
    if ($ima == $images) {
       echo "yes";} 

    else {
       echo "no";
}
?>
```

Comment: I think you can use `in_array($ima, $images);` ?

Comment: or you can change `if ($ima == $images)` to `if ($ima == $images[$i])`

Comment: why you did `md5(file_get_contents($ima));` ?

Comment: All thanks 
But I have another question if the picture has some additions, for example the picture has been added to have a large logo in the middle of the picture
When I look for it I will not find the picture
Can add condition
The proportion of image similarity is 65% if accepted and less than 50% does not accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

```
<?php 
$ima="image1.PNG";

$md5image1 = md5(file_get_contents($ima));

$images=array( "image1.PNG","image2.PNG","image3.PNG","image4.PNG"  ); 
srand(time()); 
shuffle($images); 

if (in_array("$ima", $images))
   {
         echo "Search found";
   }
    else
            {
              echo "Search not found";
            }
?>
```

Comment: All thanks to you are working now
But I have another question if the picture has some additions, for example the picture has been added to have a large logo in the middle of the picture
When I look for it I will not find the picture
Can add condition
The proportion of image similarity is 65% if accepted and less than 50% does not accept